# How to make dynamic background color change in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, background-color

I am trying to make the background color dynamically changing like a disco light.
But there is an error saying that Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method. I added more codes as request.

Here is code

```
class DiscoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_blink)

        var btnBackground = findViewById<Button>(R.id.disco_btn)
        var bgColor = 1
        btnBackground.setOnClickListener {
            when (bgColor) {
                1 -> {
                    btnBackground.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_center_gradient)
                    bgColor = 2
                }
                2 -> {
                    btnBackground.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_edge_color)
                    bgColor = 3
                }
                3 -> {
                    btnBackground.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_gradient)
                    bgColor=1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/disco_btn"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/disco"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_display_blink**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you please show your xml file i think you used worng id : disco_btn

Comment: I added more codes

Comment: Which line causing you the error? Post your logcat.

Comment: disco_btn.setOnClickListner use this

Comment: Line    `btnBackground.setOnClickListener {` makes .NullPointerException

Comment: Button has to be part of `activity_display_blink`.

Comment: @Amitpandey I edited it. But there is still the same error.

Comment: @ADM How can I use separately? There is disco_button on the mainActivity. And when it clicks, I want to use dynamic color changing on activity_display_blink. I checked the link, but I cannot understand how to edit from that link.

Comment: @ADM The app I am trying to make has more functions that need different activities. I am not asking two activities in one time. I am asking when the button is clicked on one activity, then the function shows at the different activity.